# Querying or Merging One-to-Many Relationship without Duplicating Entries of the Result

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, one-to-many

I have 2 very large data sets. The first "Main Table" is a unique list. The second "Reference Table" is a one-to-many relationship with the "Main Table".

**Objective:**
Query with filters across both data sets but display the results without duplicating the entries of the "Main Table". I don't want the user to scroll through 200 rows of the same line item just because the fields of the one-to-many "Reference Table" are highly unique.

Are there any techniques to deal with this?

All I can think of is sequentially appending the rows of the "Reference Table" as Columns to the "Main Table", like; a_1, b_1, a_2, b_2,...

Here is an example of the data sets:
[data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UkHrB.jpg)

I'm working with C#, ASP.NET, SQL Server 2016, Entity Framework

Comment: If you need to display this data in table format then you can go with parent and child tables, where main table data display in the parent table and you have one icon with each row to expand/collapse the data, once user expand the row then child table will be loaded with it's reference records...https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html

Comment: That's perfect, thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can get a lot of functionality by splitting your query into two parts:

```
using (MainContext ctx = new MainContext()) {
  var rows =  from main in ctx.Main
              select new 
              {
                Main = main,
                References = from r in ctx.References
                             where r.Id == main.Id
                             select r
              }

  // Do something with your rows
}
```

This will send one query to the DB and return one entity per row in `Main`, with a separate property that will contain all of that `Main` row's metadata.

IF you send this back to client using, for example, a WebAPI call, the data on the client would look like:

```
[{
  main: { id: ..., x: ..., y: ..., z: ...},
  references: [{ a: ..., b: ... }, {a: ..., b: ... }, ... ]
},
...,
]
```

Comment: If you explain how you want to use the data next, I can elaborate on how to manipulate the data

Comment: Could you please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52141824/dynamic-query-in-c-sharp-using-entity-framework-and-jquery-datatables for more details on the data/ logic. I think your answer here is relevant to this question.

Comment: The question was deleted?

Comment: I had temporarily solved the issue. Please check this one:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52324549/most-effective-dynamic-query-or-predicate-builder-in-asp-net-with-c-entity-fra